# How can I automatically enable the shift key?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, autocomplete, uitextfield

When the user types in my text field, I want the first letter of every word to be capitalised. One way of doing this is use `textField.autocapitalisationType`, which autocorrects every word after the user has typed it - but this method is causing separate problems for me (see my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884852/how-do-i-get-around-my-uitextfields-huge-auto-correct-dismissal-area)).

The Contacts app uses a different approach - when the user types a name, the shift key auto-highlights at the start of every word. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a different approach -- the autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords is identical to this (the shift key auto-enables at every new word), just like Contacts app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *should* result in the text field capitalizing each word:

`textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;`

Alternatively, if you made the text field in Interface Builder, you could set its `Capitalization` property to `Words`.

Comment: Ahh... I was using my Mac keyboard to type with the iPhone simulator, so I wasn't seeing the expected behaviour.

Comment: It will not work if its simulator or if Auto-Capitalisation is off from settings of iDevice/iOS.

Answer (score 1):

From the [iOS Developer Library documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html):

> This property determines at what times the Shift key is automatically
>   pressed, thereby making the typed character a capital letter. The
>   default value for this property is
>   UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences.

I believe this describes what you are looking for. The value you want is `UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords`.